# Implementing cc address

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that works as intended:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Set myItem = Item
End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim oAccount As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oMail As MailItem

Set oAccount = Application.ActiveExplorer
MsgBox (oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store)

If oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store = "test@test.com" Then
    MsgBox ("CC needs to be added")
Else
    MsgBox ("no need to add CC")
End If
End Sub
```

I would like to add something like oAccount.CC = "email_address" to get carbon copy field filled automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
set Recip = myItem.Recipients.Add("user@test.demo")
Recip.Type = olCC
```